# Catching AccessViolationException on separate thread

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I'm calling a native library that might be unstable and I want to make sure my C# app can survive a potential `AccessViolationException`. I found a way to catch the exceptions using `<legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true" />` in my `App.config`. Since the crash happens on a separate thread that I don't care about (I don't care if it dies), is it safe to keep my application running? If not, are there any mechanisms that would allow me to sandbox the native code to prevent crashes?

I don't just want to log the crash, I'm really trying to survive `AccessViolationException`.

I've tried executing the code in another `AppDomain` but it doesn't really help since it runs in the same process. I also already have a backup solution that relies on a new `Process`, and an IPC channel to communicate, but that's hard to maintain and debug. If I could do it in the main process that would simplify things a lot.

If you want to create an environment to test, just create a simple Win32 library with a single function that causes a crash (`AccessViolationException`).

**C Header:**

`__declspec(dllexport) void do_crash();`

**C Source:**

```
void do_crash()
{
    int *b = NULL;
    int c = b[3000];
}
```

**C# source:**

```
[DllImport("CrashLib.dll", EntryPoint = "do_crash")]
extern static void DoCrash();

static void Main(string[] args)
{   
    ExecuteSandboxed(delegate
    {
        DoCrash();
    });

    // Even if there's a AccessViolationException, I can keep going

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void ExecuteSandboxed(Action action)
{
    try
    {
        Task.Run(action).Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Success");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Isun I know how to handle them, I'm wondering if it's safe to keep going, and if not, if there's any other way to keep going safely

Comment: The article (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx#Two) explains the idea in grate detail, but in general it is safe to keep going as the main thread's stack will stay clean. Unlike `OutOfMemoryException` `AccessViolationException` isn't fatal to the entire application.

Comment: Excellent! you should post this as the answer..

Answer (score 0):

### Exceptions in a Nutshell

The very basic idea behind exceptions is to say "This cannot be done" and to prevent the application from continuing with a corrupted state. When an exception is raised it usually allows for the application to current the situation and continue execution. This is done by rewinding the call stack and looking for exception handlers (`try-catch` blocks).

Exceptions can come from 3 major sources:

- The application itself (using `throw ...`)
- The OS - Exceptions such as `FileNotFoundException`
- The CPU - Exception such as `DivideByZeroException` (which is raised because ALU can't preform such calculation)

The scariest exceptions by far are those raised by the CPU since they can leave it in an invalid state.

Furthermore exceptions can classified into one of three kinds:

- Invalid Operation - Such exceptions are thrown when the application attempts to preform an invalid operation. Actions such as accessing nonexistent files, dividing by zero and so on.
- Invalid thread state - Such exceptions are thrown when the state of a given thread is corrupted. Situations such as runtime-stack corruption are a possible cause.
- Invalid process (application) state - Such exception are thrown when the entire application is in an invalid state. Running out of memory is a good example.

Each kind of exception is more severe then the one before. The first will terminate the current procedure and start call-stack rewind. The second will terminate the entire thread. And the last will terminate the entire application.

**Note:** The termination process is much more involved and exceptions are not really divided into the three kinds.

### Understanding `AccessViolationException`

Now that we have a basic understanding of exceptions we can predict the state an `AccessViolationException` will leave our application in.

**First of all, who throws the exception?** This is kind of a trick question* but in practice it is thrown by the OS when it realizes that the address is not yet allocated to the process.

**What kind of exception is it?** Since the exception has nothing to do with the state of the thread nor the application; we just attempted to access "nonexistent" memory (much like we may attempt to access nonexistent files). This is clearly an `Invalid Operation` exception.

**`AccessViolationException` is an Invalid Operation exception from the OS.** Now that we know that we can safely continue execution sine we know for certain that we didn't invalided the CPU state, nor the Application state, nor the Thread state; we just attempted something illegal.